# WiFi to Ethernet bridge that is not an extender or AP

Tags: wifi, networking, network-adapter

I have a couple of systems that I need to connect to my WiFi that only have access via an Ethernet port.  When looking around I see a ton of cheap WiFi extenders/APs that have built in Ethernet ports, but from what I can see online these can only be configured as WiFi extender (creating a shadow WiFi network) or as an AP (creating a new WiFi network).

What I am after is something that bridges my WiFi to Ethernet but does not act as an extender or AP.  Does such a thing exist?  Or can things like the *Netgear AC1200 WiFi Range Extender* or *TP-Link RE350 AC1200 Wi-Fi Range Extender* actually be configured as I want?

I can't tell from looking at the user manuals online, and I don't want to drop $20-$30 just to find out that a device can't do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around I discovered that OpenWRT firmware can be set up to do exactly what I want, and that GL.iNet products come pre-installed with OpenWRT. So I am going to try a [GL-AR150](https://www.gl-inet.com/products/gl-ar150/)